# F_checksal is not a procedure or is undefined when compiling plsql

Tags: plsql

When I am trying to compile this plsql I keep getting this error message:

```
'F_checksal is not a procedure or is undefined'
```

This is the code:

```
declare
  e_high_increase EXCEPTION;
  old_sal NUMBER;
  function f_checkSal(i_sal number,i_old_sal IN OUT NUMBER) return VARCHAR2 is
  begin
  if((i_sal/old_sal)*100>300) then
  raise e_high_increase;
  else  
  return 'yes';
  end if;
  exception when e_high_increase then
  insert into t_logerror(error_tx) values ('this is user exception');
  dbms_output.put_line('this is user exception');
  return 'No';
  end;
begin
select sal into old_sal FROM emp where empno=153;
f_checksal(30000,old_sal);
update emp set sal=30000 where empno=153;  
end;
```

Comment: Is this a script file?  You cannot create a function like this.  You  have to create the function separately, then call from the SQL scripts.

Comment: @OldProgrammer, it's certainly possible to declare functions within an anonymous block.

Answer (score 1):

It's just your call to your function that needs to be changed.

You can consume the result with a call to a procedure (e.g. `DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line( f_checksal(30000,old_sal));`), or assign it to a local variable, e.g. `RESULT := f_checksal(30000,old_sal);`

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is way off.  You need to first CREATE the function, then reference it in your pl/sql block:

Step1 :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_checksal (i_sal NUMBER, i_old_sal IN OUT NUMBER)
   RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
   old_sal           NUMBER;
   e_high_increase   EXCEPTION;
BEGIN
   IF ((i_sal / old_sal) * 100 > 300)
   THEN
      RAISE e_high_increase;
   ELSE
      RETURN 'yes';
   END IF;
EXCEPTION
   WHEN e_high_increase
   THEN
      INSERT INTO t_logerror
                  (error_tx
                  )
           VALUES ('this is user exception'
                  );

      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('this is user exception');
      RETURN 'No';
END;
/
```

Step 2:

```
DECLARE
   old_sal   NUMBER;
   RESULT    VARCHAR2 (100);
BEGIN
   SELECT sal
     INTO old_sal
     FROM emp
    WHERE empno = 153;

   RESULT := f_checksal (30000, old_sal);

   UPDATE emp
      SET sal = 30000
    WHERE empno = 153;
END;
```

Note that your function has a return value that you were not assinging in the calling code.

Comment: The syntax is *not* "way off". You don't need to create the function in order to use it in the block. Only if you need to call the function *from SQL* would you need to create it as a separate schema object.